# typing definitions without circular imports

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a package where I would like to

1. use typing for code-hinting
2. export some of the typing variables for users of the package to allow them to use typing as well, but simultaneously use them in the package it-self

My main problem is that this will often result in circular imports.

Consider a code:

`package/foo.py`:

```py
class A:
    def hello(self, arg: Union[str, dict]) -> Any:
```

`package/bar.py`:

```py
from . import foo
# I can't do: from package.typing import BarBType
class B:
    def hello(self, arg: Union[foo.A, str, dict]) -> Any:
```

I would then like to have a typing subpackage:

`package/typing.py`:

```py
from package import foo
from package import bar
BarBType = Union[foo.A, str, dict]
FooBarType = Union[foo.A, bar.B]
```

However, this forces a duplicate definition of the `hello_arg_type`, i.e. I cannot self-use it in the `package.bar`?

How should one structure the files and typing information in packages which exposes complex typing constructs that should be used locally, but also exposed globally?
I would prefer if everything could be in-line typed, i.e. no stub files (`.pyi`). It would also be great if documentation utilities could use this for improving the final document.

I have thought about exposing these where they are used, i.e. in `bar.py` define the types, then let `typing.py` import everything that it will expose. This just seems a bit counter-intuitive...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING

Comment: Check out `typing.TYPE_CHECKING`

Comment: @TomMcLean  would this work in documentation cases where sphinx uses the arguments for references?